# What are the criterias Google Maps Navigation uses to suggest a route?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I'm asking this question because of a very specific issue I'm facing a lot of times. Google maps suggests me a longer + more time consuming routes sometimes when it has the shorter, less time consuming routes. What is the logic behind this suggestion.

I will share a screenshot of this happens in the Google Maps Web (since I have to match the perfect timing to make that happen in mobile but in the web I can change the departure time and reproduce the scenario. I will update the post as soon as it happens the next time on the mobile.)

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots of this occurring?  I've not had this happen to me that I can recall.

Comment: Hi @SiXandSeven8ths , updated the post with an screenshot. It is a screenshot from web since I cannot reproduce the scenario on my mobile but I can do it on the web via changing the departure time. But I can assure you that this is the result I get if I try it on the mobile at the set time.

Comment: Traffic conditions , private roads could be one reason. Other reason in Maps settings > Route options - have you selected any that prevent showing the shortest - like *Avoid Motorways or avoid toll roads?* (accessible from 3 dot menu on the app)

Comment: @beeshyams Nope, I have not restricted any result with those options. And for sure, the route the map suggesting is the best from my experience. I am just curious on how the map gives this suggestion and what might be the ingredients beyond the distance and duration?

Comment: It looks like traffic - I just checked on my app . Click steps at the bottom and see the congestion reported Vis-a-Vis the other route

Comment: In one case it was orange-red while the longer route had yellow - indicating less congestion

Comment: I have no evidence for this, but I think that for UX reasons it's designed to offer you worse alternative routes so that you can choose to reject them and you feel more agency in the navigation, instead of simply doing as you're told. It's like the IKEA effect, but for decision-making.